# Proof verification: $x_n \rightarrow a$ and $x_n \rightarrow b$ then $a=b$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in a metric space $S$. Prove: if $x_n \rightarrow a$ and $x_n \rightarrow b$ then $a=b$.

Assume $a \neq b$. Take two balls $B_r(a)$ and $B_r(b)$ with such an $r$ that $B_r(a) \cap B_r(b)=\emptyset$. Then WLOG assume there is a sequence $(x_n)$ that converges to $a$. Then for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there is $N \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $d(x_n,a) < \varepsilon$ for all $n \geq N$. Then for $\varepsilon < r$, all the terms of the sequence past the corresponding $N$ are in $B_r(a)$ and not in $B_r(b)$, so the sequence certainly does not converge to $b$.

Is it correct enough?

Comment: It's all good to me

Comment: If you want to be more rigorous, give an argument on why you can choose $r>0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's mostly fine, but it's even nicer if you say "and take $r = d(b, a)/2 > 0$"; then your reader *knows* that $B_r(a) \cap B_r(b) = \emptyset$. Also, "WLOG assume there is a sequence $(x_n)$ that converges to $a$" is a bunch of fancy words that say nothing. Why? Because the sequence $a, a, \ldots,$ is a sequence that converges to $a$. There's no "loss of generality" here, and no need to assume anything. Furthermore, you can't *assume* anything about $(x_n)$ -- it's **given** in the hypotheses.

So a rewrite might be:

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in a metric space $S$. Prove: if $x_n \rightarrow a$ and $x_n \rightarrow b$ then $a=b$.

Assume $a \neq b$, and let $r = \frac{d(a, b)}{2}$. Because $a \ne b$, we have $r > 0$. Then $B_r(a) \cap B_r(b)=\emptyset$.

By definition of convergence, for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there is $N \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $d(x_n,a) < \varepsilon$ for all $n \geq N$. In particular, for $\varepsilon = r$, there is such an $N$. That means that 
$$
d(x_n, a) < r
$$
for all $n > N$, 
and hence (because of the empty intersection of balls) that
$$
d(x_n, b) > r
$$
for all $n > N$. But that contradicts the definition of $x_n \to b$, for the choice $\varepsilon = r$.

Comment: Thank you. With WLOG I meant converges to either $a$ or $b$, doesn't matter. I thought $(x_n)$ was just any sequence in a metric space, in particular one not converging to anything.

Comment: "WLOG I meant converges to either a or b, doesn't matter." But you're given, in the hypotheses, that it DOES converge to $a$, which is all you needed and used in the next sentence. So cite that -- simplicity is better.  As for "I thought $(x_n)$ was just any sequence...", that *can't* be the case, because not "just any sequence" converges to $a$. If you meant "I thought that whenever we want to talk about a sequence, we can call it $(x_n)$," that's only partly true: you can do so only if $(x_n)$ doesn't already denote something else. Otherwise it's like calling all the actors "Hamlet". :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simpler argument.

Take $\varepsilon>0$.
Then $d(x_n,a) < \varepsilon$ and $d(x_n,b) < \varepsilon$ for all $n$ sufficiently large.

But then $d(a,b) \le d(a,x_n)+ d(x_n,b) = d(x_n,a)+ d(x_n,b) < 2\varepsilon$.

Since $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary, this can only happen if $d(a,b)=0$, which implies $a=b$.